Prove that best predictor for Gaussian process is linear
It's well known that if we have finite sequence $t_1 < \dots < t_n$ and gaussian process Z, then conditional expectation $E(Z(t_n) | Z(t_{n - 1}), \dots, Z(t_1))$ is linear function of variables $Z(t_{n - 1}), \dots, Z(t_1)$. But many sources point out that it is true for more general case: let $F_t = \sigma(Z_s: s < t)$ and we consider random variable $E(Z(t) | F_t)$. Then $E(Z(t) | F_t)$ is linear functional of $Z_s, s < t$. How can we prove it using finite-dimensional case?
Many thanks for your help!
